# Node version problems

Tags: node.js, vue.js, homebrew

I'm still bad at ubuntu and encountering some problems with my node versions. I just uninstalled it with brew. In my vue project I have :

When I run node -v I get :

```
v10.19.0
```

If I run node -v out of my project I have :

```
bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type (equivalent to type of file not found)
```

However, in my Vue project, when I run :

> npm run serve

I get :

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
...
Node.js v17.0.1
```

I tried to uninstall it through brew, and reinstall, I still have issues. When I reinstall through brew I have node -v saying v17.0.1 too.

I don't understand why my vue project doesn't have the same version of node.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I freshly tried again this morning. Everythings works. I guess rebooting was the solution.
So my node version is 17 everywhere.

I have no more error on my npm run serve and if you ever need to know, for tailwind css in vue project, you need node version superior to 14.